# What is the bitmap's meaning in mdstat

Tags: linux, mdadm, software-raid

Not long ago, [I have created new Software RAID array (`mdadm`) with 4 drives in RAID6](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/320330/126755). It seems to work just fine. `mdstat` follows:

```
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md0 : active raid6 sda1[0] sde1[3] sdd1[2] sdb1[1]
      1953260544 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 0/8 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

What is bugging me, is the *`bitmap: 0/8 pages`* part, which I don't understand.

The question is: Is this a potential problem or not? And please, elaborate a little on what the *bitmap* is actually about.

Full detail of this array follows:

```
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Tue Nov  1 13:44:13 2016
     Raid Level : raid6
     Array Size : 1953260544 (1862.77 GiB 2000.14 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 976630272 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Fri Dec  2 13:05:18 2016
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : backup-server:0  (local to host backup-server)
           UUID : 023f115d:212b130c:f05b072b:b14c2819
         Events : 1664

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       3       8       65        3      active sync   /dev/sde1
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[The bitmap line in `/proc/mdstat`](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Mdstat#bitmap_line) indicates how much memory is being used to cache [the write-intent bitmap](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Write-intent_bitmap).

Basically, in RAID setups with redundant devices, `mdadm` can use a "bitmap" to keep track of which blocks may be out of sync (because they've been written to). When a block is written to the `mdadm` device, it is flagged in the bitmap, and then written to the underlying devices; once enough time has passed without activity in the block that `mdadm` can be sure that it's been written to all the devices, the flag is removed from the bitmap. It's useful to speed up resyncs after a system crash, or after a disk is removed and re-added (without being changed).

In your case, 0/8 means that no memory is being used for the in-memory bitmap cache. This is a good thing: there's a good chance that all the underlying devices are synced. (In theory there could be entries in the on-disk bitmap that aren't cached in memory, but that's unlikely if the cache is completely empty.)

[`md(4)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/md.4.html) has more information.

Comment: What does the `chunk` on the `bitmap` line mean? I would guess that's the part of actual RAID device covered by a single bit of bitmap but I couldn't find any documentation to say this.